# Getting an answer back after merging accounts

Tags: feature-request, answers, user-accounts

I answered [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18374/what-forms-of-water-ice-have-been-observed-and-verified-in-the-solar-system?r=SearchResults), but at the time I had two accounts by accident and had to merge them.  When I did so the account that survived was the one that was not credited with my answer leaving my answer "orphaned"  How to transfer the answer back to the active account?  Thanks again, I am apparently too new to SE to know what to do when things go wrong.

Comment: it looks as though it hasn't been merged - perhaps you had three accounts?

Comment: I thought I merged them.  I pressed OK for confirming the request when I got emails.

Comment: When was that? I think merging is a manual process that is put into a moderator queue **after** you OK the emails. When my accounts merged I owned all my answers. It took a couple of days to be actioned, I think - but it was over a year ago.

Comment: Ok now I know, thanks.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Did you ever get this sorted out? It looks like there are still separate accounts.

Comment: looks like he did @called2voyage